# Obtener ViewHolder de un elemento seleccionado en RecyclerView (Problema con método OnClick anónimo)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

alguna idea de ¿cómo obtener datos de una variable para almacenarlos por fuera de un método anónimo?
Mi código es el siguiente, lo que quiero es obtener el `ViewHolder` para tomar el texto del View(TextView) que contiene. Me tira problemas para acceder por ser un método anónimo.

```
final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewElement;

        ((MyAdapter) mAdapter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
                Log.i("RecyclerViewPosition", "Posicion en RecyclerView: " + pos);
                viewElement = recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Quieres hacer eso al darle click a un elemento de un recycler view?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, podrías colocar mas datos? quieres pasar el valor de un `TextView` de un adaptador a una activity/fragment? y en que momento?  al dar clic?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue crear una variable pública para el `ViewHolder`, en realidad no tenía la necesidad de usar ese valor por fuera del método, ya que lo que debería hacer es justo al seleccionar un usuario del `RecyclerView` es ir al siguiente Fragment con esa información.

```
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder;

((MyAdapter) mAdapter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
            viewHolder = (MyAdapter.MyViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
            //Estoy accediendo al textView del ViewHolder
            String usuario = viewHolder.textView.getText().toString();
            Log.i("RecyclerViewPosition", "Posicion en RecyclerView: " + pos);
            Log.i("UserInRecyclerView", usuario);
    }
});
```